# google.loader.ClientLocation returning emply strings for address items

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Why Google API Loader Client address location is returning an empty string for a working country for years?.
The object is here but address items are empty.

After API key.

```
google.load("maps",'3',{other_params:'sensor=true'});  
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
    if (google.loader.ClientLocation)  
    {  
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city is ""  
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region is ""  
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code is ""  
google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude is OK  
google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude is OK
```

Answer (score 0):

`Google.load.ClientLocation` is no more supported by google team dev. The `load.ClientLocation` is only returning a very bad accurate latitude and longitude and no more addresses items.

This is very bad because now if user not accepting to return geolocation using HTML5, you need to use IPlocation to search a country and city.

I think that is very egoist from a great company like Google, many websites need to serve contents identifiing cities, countries, languages as a minimal and `ClientLocation` function it was a easier way. Now to make this, you need to call navigators ask to users, get the lat,lon and get use an external call to another service to see a simple country code!. It's not to simplify my applications. Country or city locations in not like GPS position at 100 m It's a basic fonction of many developers an users. Cheers.

See:

- [Is google.loader.clientlocation still supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195837/is-google-loader-clientlocation-still-supported)